# How to fix this DataFrame warning : SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x

I know they were a number of question on this warning. I read all and still could figure it out why this line gives me the warning:

This is the function I tried to call:

```
def createFeature(df):

    df.loc[:, 'PCT_change'] = (df.loc[:, 'Close'] - df.loc[:, 'Close'].shift(1))/df.loc[:, 'Close'].shift(1)*100.0


return df
```

When I called the above function with this command:

```
stock_train_reform = createFeature(stock_train)
```

The warnings appear as

> stock_train_reform = createFeature(stock_train)
>   /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.5/pandas/core/indexing.py:560:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

I don't know how to fix this warning. Please help
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Thank you Miriam. I found this and try to follow by using .loc but the warning is still remain.

Comment: Actually, I just put "df.is_copy = False" to clarify that I didn't want to copy in the "createFeature" function. It works. I hope this isn't make my result goes wrong.